# How to add row for a nested antd react table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to add a new row to the nested table : https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cloud-f5v2bh ,

But unable to do so, can someone guide me on how can i add a row to a nested table where data populates for parent and child field as well as I am able to edit parent and children entry.

Thanks !